# Generating Random Real numbers with certain numbers not included

Tags: functions, random

I'm writing a program that i need 1000 real number between -3 and 6. the code that I used for generating and saving them was

```
l = RandomReal[{-3, 6}, 1000]
```

But I want to be sure none of these numbers are equal to 3.How can I do that in a short and nice way? How can I generate these numbers in a way that I don't need to check for 3 being in list?

Comment: It might help to explain why you wan't this. In theory the odds of generating 3 exactly is infinitesimally small (it may in fact be impossible depending on the specifics of the generator) and as such not really worth bothering about. If you are rounding off a some point this may be different.

Comment: I might ask how sure you need to be.  The probability of generating a machine number that is detected as equal to 3. is very very small.  Somewhere on the order of 10^-12 when you only generate 1000 of them in that range. It is about two orders of magnitude smaller if you are checking for equivalence (===).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Plot[PDF[MixtureDistribution[{6, 3},
        {UniformDistribution[{-3, 3 - $MachineEpsilon}], 
         UniformDistribution[{3 + $MachineEpsilon, 6}]}], x], {x, -3, 6}, 
         Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To generate your data:

```
RandomVariate[ MixtureDistribution[{6,3}, 
              {UniformDistribution[{-3, 3 - $MachineEpsilon}], 
           UniformDistribution[{3 + $MachineEpsilon, 6}]}], 500]
```

Comment: I do not believe this works.  Sorry, but -1.  Explanation to follow.

Comment: No idea whether it work ... but I do not believe it is necessary. Just using `RandomReal` should be just fine.

Comment: Nice!I just wanna vote a +1.

Answer (score 9):

I do not believe that belisarius's answer, as written, is correct, at least in *Mathematica* 10.0.1 under Windows.

In a simplified example we can see that in machine precision a three is still generated despite subtracting `$MachineEpsilon` from `3` in the range.  I narrow the range make this readily apparent:

```
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon;

SeedRandom[1]
First /@ RealDigits @ RandomReal[{3 - 5 ϵ, 3 - ϵ}, 5]
```

> ```
> {{3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
>  {2,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
>  {3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
>  {2,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
>  {2,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9}}
> ```

We can see that at least in *Mathematica* 10.0.1 `3 - ϵ` is not distinct from `3.`:

```
{3., 3 - ϵ} // FullForm
Order[3., 3 - ϵ]
```

> ```
> List[3.`, 3.`]
>
> 0
> ```

The longer formulation is not even accepted:

```
RandomVariate[
 MixtureDistribution[{6, 3},
  {UniformDistribution[{3 - 5 ϵ, 3 - ϵ}], 
   UniformDistribution[{3 + ϵ, 3 + 5 ϵ}]}], 500]
```

> ```
> UniformDistribution::lss: Parameter 2.999999999999999` at
> position {1,1} in UniformDistribution[{3.,3.}] is expected to be less
> than 3.`. 
>
> UniformDistribution::lss: Parameter 2.999999999999999` at position
> {1,1} in UniformDistribution[{3.,3.}] is expected to be less than 3.`.
> ```

This is despite `3 - 5 ϵ` and `3 - ϵ` being distinct.  If I expand the range sufficiently the input is accepted, but as one might expect following the behavior illustrated earlier three is included in the result:

```
SeedRandom[1]

RandomVariate[
  MixtureDistribution[{6, 3},
   {UniformDistribution[{3 - 500 ϵ, 3 - ϵ}], 
    UniformDistribution[{3 + ϵ, 3 + 500 ϵ}]}], 5] // RealDigits
```

> ```
> {{{3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4}, 1},
>  {{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 6}, 1},
>  {{3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7}, 1},
>  {{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9}, 1},
>  {{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 4}, 1}}
> ```

For the simplified example it appears sufficient to use an offset of `2 ϵ` as this is distinct from three:

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomReal[{3 - 5 ϵ, 3 - 2 ϵ}, 500000] // RealDigits // Tally
```

> ```
> {{{{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 1}, 500000}}
> ```

However for the longer formulation this too fails.  In fact even using an offset of `100 ϵ` is insufficient!

```
SeedRandom[1]

RandomVariate[
  MixtureDistribution[{6, 3},
   {UniformDistribution[{3 - 500 ϵ, 3 - 100 ϵ}], 
    UniformDistribution[{3 + 100 ϵ, 3 + 500 ϵ}]}], 5] // RealDigits
```

> ```
> {{{3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7}, 1},
>  {{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 4}, 1},
>  {{3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4}, 1},
>  {{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 3, 7}, 1},
>  {{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9}, 1}}
> ```

As a final example observe that I can recreate belisarius's plot without using any offset at all:

```
Plot[
 PDF[
  MixtureDistribution[{6, 3},
   {UniformDistribution[{-3, 3}], 
    UniformDistribution[{3, 6}]}], x],
 {x, -3, 6},
 Filling -> Axis
]
```

[image]

---

### Further problems

Contrary to what is stated (and illustrated) above an offset of `2 ϵ` may not be sufficient for `RandomReal` either.  **There is apparently instability in this process if not a bug.**  While continuing to experiment I got a different result:

```
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon;

SeedRandom[1]

RandomReal[{3 - 5 ϵ, 3 - 2 ϵ}, 500000] // RealDigits // Tally
```

> ```
> {{{{3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 1}, 124641},
>  {{{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 1}, 375359}}
> ```

Yet the same code in a fresh kernel again yields:

> ```
> {{{{2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 1}, 500000}}
> ```

---

### Proposed solution

Since I am unable to recommend any method to directly avoid generating a specific value within a range, especially in light of the apparently unstable behavior I am experiencing from `RandomReal`, I can only suggest a filtering approach which will be admittedly slow.  Here with integers for an easier illustration:

```
RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 50] //. {4 :> RandomInteger[{1, 5}]}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2,
>  5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1}
> ```

This should robustly assure that no `4` appears in the output, and that the output is always of length `50`, no matter how many `4`'s appear in the initial result.  The same method can be applied to real values.  This is a great deal of overhead for an unlikely event however, so consider your alternatives carefully.

Comment: I didn't check this or even look too hard at this question/answers. But, it should be `3*(1 - $MachineEpsilon)` and `3*(1 + $MachineEpsilon)`, not as written in belisarius's answer. After that, it should work correctly (if there are no FP bugs in the distribution implementations, &c.).

Comment: `m = $MachineEpsilon; RandomVariate[
 MixtureDistribution[{1, 1}, {UniformDistribution[{-2 m, -m}],  UniformDistribution[{m, 2 m}]}], 500]`

Comment: @belisarius I don't follow? Anyway, reading this answer more carefully, I see that (i.e., the error shows that) Andy (or whoever else wrote or helped to write these) has been bitten by `Internal\`$EqualTolerance` and friends. These are sufficiently obscure that it wouldn't surprise me at all that there is at least one person working at WRI who is writing numerical code and doesn't know what they do, or considers it an irrelevant corner case.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The above comment was my original testing code to check that the Distribution functions were working at a precision compatible with MachineEpsilon. I'm in no way well versed on numerical oddities, so I may be being naive.

Comment: Amusingly(?), `SetPrecision[Union@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{1.-$MachineEpsilon,1.}],100],Infinity]` shows that *Mathematica* also does not seem to be quite sure which definition of $\epsilon$ it wants to use--is it 1/2 ULP (LAPACK convention), or 1 ULP (ISO C convention)?

Comment: @belisarius `$MachineEpsilon` is normalized to 1, i.e. it's a relative, not an absolute, difference. There do exist plenty of valid FP numbers smaller than it, but not any two that vary by a fraction less than it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Ha! The first comment is really curious. I'm aware of the second comment, and that is the intended usage

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, for any continuous distribution ... which includes your Uniform distribution ... $P(X=3) = 0$. So, theoretically, your question leaves you with nothing to worry about.

Practically, for `RandomReal` to hit a perfect 3 ... should be equally impossible. Perhaps, as a matter of machine-precision, you are worried about whether mma might hypothetically assert a real is equal to an integer. It should not.

But, if it really, really bothers you, ... simply generate your pseudo-random data ... check if it contains a 3 ... and if it does, delete it.

Just out of interest, here are 100 million pseudo-random numbers drawn between 1.9999 and 2.00001 ...

```
data = RandomReal[{1.9999, 2.00001}, 10^8];
```

and there is not one integer 2:

```
MemberQ[data, 2]
```

> False

Nor should there be.

Comment: But perhaps there is a 2.0. Yes, the real number 2 is actually thought of by *Mathematica* as a uniform distribution having width `3 $MachineEpsilon`, and yes, "equality" is not really defined for distributions, but this is a unique oddity (some would say perversion) of *Mathematica* and probably not what the OP is asking about. Practically speaking, the calculation is done over a finite set of rationals, not reals or distributions or anything else.

Comment: The OP's question specifies his aversion to the integer 3, not 3.0. I cannot say if he intends something else.

Comment: Yes. P(X=3)=0. This is the correct answer to this question.

Comment: The OP clearly states that they do not want numbers "equal to 3" in the result. Integers are a subset of the reals and 3 is equal to 3.0 (but it is not a pattern match in *Mathematica*, as you surely know). You are obviously correct if *Mathematica* really draws from a uniform distribution over the reals, but given that (like every other computer system) it does this only using the approximation of floating point arithmetic, then either your answer is wishful thinking, or your math is faulty.

Comment: `data = RandomReal[{1.99999999, 2.00000001}, 10^8]; MemberQ[data, 2.] (* -> True *)`

Comment: There are two possibilities: (i) if the OP wishes to avoid exact integer 3 (as the question currently states), then there is no problem, theoretically or practically, as you seem to understand. (ii) If the OP wishes to avoid real 3.0 (which is a different question to that posed by the OP, but perhaps his intention), then the solution is to catch them (with whatever desired tolerance) and remove them.

Comment: The question does not specify anything about integers specifically, just "numbers equal to 3"--and, anyway, you seem to be intent on interpreting the putative restriction to integers as referring to data type rather than numerical value. In some narrow sense, I do agree, you are correct in what you say. Unfortunately, I fear that this sense has little or perhaps nothing to do with the question the OP actually asks.

Comment: My fear is that the OP has little sense about what he is asking.

Answer (score 5):

*[Update: Corrected error in and improved first method.]*

Given the upvotes on the question, there seems to be, or to have been, some interest in this question.  As has been mentioned, based on a continuous probability model, the chances of getting a `3.` is nil.  But `RandomReal` is a discrete approximation so there is some small, positive probability of getting a particular number.

I can read the question in two ways, to avoid getting the particular number `3.` or to avoid getting numbers `Equal` to the number 3.  These mean different things in *Mathematica*.

#### No `3.`'s

One way to avoid getting a `3.` is to replace them like this:

```
pos3 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Position[x, 3.], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
l = ReplacePart[#, pos3[#] :> NestWhile[RandomReal[{3, 6}] &, 3., pos3[{#}] =!= {} &]] &@
      RandomReal[{-3, 6}, 1000]
```

It turns out a sure way to match exactly the number `3.` is to use a compiled function with the `RuntimeOptions` setting `"CompareWithTolerance" -> False`.  This is achieved with `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` along with some other speed-ups, like no overflow checking.  See the section at the end for a little hitch with the replacement `/. 3. -> ..`, which matches more than `3.` and cannot be used to strictly eliminate only threes.

#### None equal to `3.`

To avoid getting a number equal to `3.`, we need to understand how `Equal` works on approximate real numbers.  It compares with a tolerance that is determined by `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``, although testing shows that is not exactly true.  It seems to depend on the bits in the binary representation of the floating-point number.  The thresholds for equality with `3.` should be about

```
3. ± 0.5 * (3 * 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance * $MachineEpsilon)
```

Where the `0.5` comes from the approximate boundary for rounding toward `3.`  We can solve for the exact boundaries, by first approximating them with `FindRoot`:

```
thresholdPlus = x /. FindRoot[
   Boole[3. == 3. + x*3*10^Internal`$EqualTolerance*$MachineEpsilon] - 1/2,
   {x, 0.5, 0.505}]
thresholdMinus = x /. FindRoot[
   Boole[3. == 3. - x*3*10^Internal`$EqualTolerance*$MachineEpsilon] - 1/2,
   {x, 0.49, 0.5}]
```

> FindRoot::brmp: The root has been bracketed as closely as possible with machine precision...

```
(*  0.502604  *)
```

> FindRoot::brmp: The root has been bracketed as closely as possible with machine precision...

```
(*  0.497396  *)
```

We can adjust these thresholds manually until we find the last point at which `Equal` returns `True`:

```
3. == 3. + (1 - 2 $MachineEpsilon) thresholdPlus *
    3 * 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance * $MachineEpsilon
3. == 3. - (1 - $MachineEpsilon) thresholdMinus * 
    3 * 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance * $MachineEpsilon
(*
  True
  True
*)
```

And reset the thresholds:

```
thresholdPlus = (1 - 2 $MachineEpsilon) thresholdPlus; 
thresholdMinus = (1 - $MachineEpsilon) thresholdMinus;
```

Now construct a function to use to pick out the `3.`'s in a list:

```
equal3[x_] := 
  UnitStep[x - (3. - thresholdMinus*3*10^Internal`$EqualTolerance*$MachineEpsilon)] *
   UnitStep[(3. + thresholdPlus*3*10^Internal`$EqualTolerance*$MachineEpsilon) - x];
```

Then finally we can construct our list of random numbers like this:

```
l = FixedPoint[
 ReplacePart[#, SparseArray[equal3@#]["NonzeroPositions"] :> RandomReal[{-3, 6}]] &,
 RandomReal[{-3, 6}, 1000]]
```

It takes only about 4-6 times longer than a simple `RandomReal`, not counting the time it takes to figure out how to set up the code, which is significant.

#### Performance

```
TableForm[
 Table[
  {"10"^n,
   RandomReal[{-3, 6}, 10^n]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
   ReplacePart[#, 
         pos3[#] :> NestWhile[RandomReal[{3, 6}] &, 3., pos3[{#}] =!= {} &]
         ] &@RandomReal[{-3, 6}, 10^n]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
   FixedPoint[
       ReplacePart[#, 
         SparseArray[equal3@#]["NonzeroPositions"] :> 
          RandomReal[{-3, 6}]] &,
       RandomReal[{-3, 6}, 10^n]]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
   RandomVariate[
       MixtureDistribution[{6 - 2 $MachineEpsilon, 
         3 - 2 $MachineEpsilon}, {UniformDistribution[{-3, 
           3. - 2 $MachineEpsilon}], 
         UniformDistribution[{3. + 2 $MachineEpsilon, 6}]}], 10^n]; //
      RepeatedTiming // First},
  {n, 2, 7}],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {Length, RandomReal, ReplacePart, SparseArray, "Mixture"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first method I gave (called `ReplacePart` in the table) is a bit faster than the `SparseArray` method, especially on shorter lists. Both add some noticeable overhead to a straight `RandomReal` call.  In the OP's use-case (length 1000), `ReplacePart` is a bit under 3 times slower.  Of course, as others have mentioned, it is highly unlikely that any replacement will ever be done.  Note, also, how slow `MixtureDistribution` is.

#### What matches 3.? -- Caveat to the first solution

Interestingly, `3.` matches two numbers (which I didn't know before):

```
{(1. - $MachineEpsilon) 3., 3. - 3*0.51 $MachineEpsilon, 3., 
  3. + 3*0.51 $MachineEpsilon, (1. + $MachineEpsilon) 3.} // FullForm
(*
  {2.999999999999999`,
   2.9999999999999996`,
   3.`,
   3.0000000000000004`, 
   3.000000000000001`}
*)

{(1. - $MachineEpsilon) 3., 3. - 3*0.51 $MachineEpsilon, 3., 
  3. + 3*0.51 $MachineEpsilon, (1. + $MachineEpsilon) 3.} /. 3. -> Infinity
(*  {3., ∞, ∞, 3., 3.}  *)
```

But if the OP is trying to avoid division by zero in, say, `1/(x-3)`, then the lower number would not need to be replaced:

```
1/((3. - 3*0.51 $MachineEpsilon) - 3)
(*  -2.2518*10^15  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = DeleteCases[Range[-3, 6], 3];
l = RandomChoice[data, {1000}]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I said I want 1000 real number between -3 and 6 with 3 not in them.your answer outputs integers.

Comment: @user2838619 If you use `RandomReal `there are no integers anyway. So, what would you expect to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to "redraw" a random number whenever a draw selects a number you wish to eliminate. Here is a compact and recursive way to do this :

```
random := With[{x = RandomReal[{-3, 6}]}, If[x == 3., random, x]];
Table[random, 1000]
```

(theoretically the code is not guaranteed to stop, although infinite running time has probability = 0).

To check that this works you can try

```
r := With[{x = RandomInteger[{-3, 6}]}, If[x == 3, r, x]];
data = Table[r, 1000];
Select[data, # == 3 &]
```

that returns

```
{}
```